# Is descriptive statistics enough to compare test scores of students in a class?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, inference, descriptive-statistics

I am reviewing the theory on hypothesis testing and the book I am reading ("Hypothesis Testing" by Jim Frost) stresses the fact that we do hypothesis testing and inferential statistic when we only have a sample and we want to learn something about a larger population.

These statements got me thinking because I am now teaching a course to a group of students and I find myself thinking about using hypothesis testing as the only way to make "safe" (read, "statistically significant") claims. However, now I am thinking that all things considered my students are my entire population; I am not interested in making claims about a larger population of students, am I? Does it make sense?

For example, consider I am taking the scores of an intermediate test and I want to see whether females are doing better than males. Is this a case where descriptive statistic (direcly compare the two means) is enough, without need for inference (say, a t-test)?

I tend to discard simple descriptive statistic because they do not account in any way for randomness: maybe some students got a very bad or good day. So I think about inference as a better option because it somehow accounts for that randomness, but I have never considered that I already have all the population from the start.

I hope you get my dilemma. Can someone help me clarifying it?

Comment: Do you want to know whether the male students could have done better or whether they did better than the female students?

Comment: Hypothesis testing is not usually a particularly helpful approach to learning about populations. I have looked at the table of contents of the book that you mentioned and it seems like it may not contain what you need in order to understand the role of hypothesis testing in making scientific inferences. I suggest that you read this chapter to get a proper context: https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/164_2019_286

Comment: Similar to DonQuiKong's question, what do you actually want to know here? What kinds of "claims" do you want to make and why?

Answer (score 14):

The question of doing inferential statistics when you have the whole population is one on which reasonable people can differ.

On one hand, it makes little sense. As you said, inferential stats involve inferring from a sample to a population. You have the population. There's nothing to infer to. This tends to be my view.

However, some people posit a sort of "super population" - a hypothetical case of some larger group such as all the classes that might have taken the test. I don't really buy this, but it's not ridiculous.

In your particular case, I think descriptive statistics are fine. If the girls did better than the boys, then they did better. You can say how much better. You can give the standard deviations, or make plots or whatever to illustrate how much better.

The super population here might be something like "all the tests I might have given" or "all the classes I might have had" but ... then, for inference to be valid, you have to assume that you have a random sample.  That may or may not be reasonable, but it's an assumption.

While there are notable statisticians who make the super population argument, I think some people are just wedded to the notion that statistics *have to* produce p values and confidence intervals. This is especially true of people who took one or two statistics courses, either undergrad or graduate. Unfortunately, many of these courses are taught by people who aren't that well trained in stats themselves.

Comment: +1. I think you already tackle the issue when you say "*you have to assume that you have a random sample*", but I'm wondering if all the implications of this sentence are obvious to someone unfamiliar with statistics and study design. Indeed, with data from just one class, we can't infer anything relative to some populations of students (e.g. students from other classes in the same school, all students at the national or international level, students from other years, etc.), and this is a distinct issue from the question of knowing if we're interested in a super population.

Comment: (In other words, I'm a bit wary about people being confused and thinking something like "I can just say that I'm interested in a super population to generalize what I observed in this class to all other classes in the country").

Answer (score 12):

I think for a test score randomness that you mentioned is what creates the population. Take one student for example. For the same test he or she could get one score on one day, and another score on another day. And the score will also vary for different tests you prepare - some will be easier for that particular student while others will be harder.

This is already a population - a population of scores this student can be observed obtaining on the tests that you prepare. We can imagine it has an average and a spread. And then if you want to compare the performance of that student with another student, while taking all of this into account, you could be using hypothesis tests.

A similar logic applies to comparing males and females. If you use descriptive statistics all you will be able to say is that on this particular test all the female students got an average of X and all the male students got an average of Y. It answer the question "which group won". But if you want to then extrapolate that to making claims about female group performing better in your class you could use an appropriate hypothesis test. Here the scores of a test on this day is just a sample of all possible tests you might have given. And there is an even broader question about who are able to learn the subject better, females or males. And here the people you have in your class compose a sample of all potential male and female students. Even those not alive or those that could potentially be born and attend your class.

Comment: That's an interesting point of view. Thanks! I can think about the population of all the students that take the same test, for example the future students of my next cohort! That scenario would make sense only if I make sure that this cohort doesn't pass down information about the test to the next cohort.

Comment: @rusiano I'm not sure if you identified this problem, but you should consider that a cohort from a given year is not a random sample from the population of "all students who take the test". Case in point: in my country, there is a generation of students who, for a few years, did not have mandatory math education in high school (politicians decided to make it optional, and women tended to choose this option less than men). If those students happened to take a math test, it would be obvious that we shouldn't consider them as a random sample of "all students who take the test over the years".

Answer (score 11):

You remind me of a recent conversation I had with a Masters student in statistics. He was working at some place that had a lot of "DS" people and one of them showed up at a meeting detailing t-tests of some group of analysts in one wing versus a group of analysts in another wing of the office. Made the claim that because the differences in the analyst groups were statistically significant, then there was in fact a difference between the groups (this is a common fallacy on it's own, but not really the major point here).

We both remarked that this scenario is a bit ridiculous. You aren't testing a hypothetical population of analyst groups in this scenario (unless you mean to test differences in these groups, like male and female, across *all* analysts across the country, and this is some kind of random sample). Here the descriptives are enough because you are forming a complete appraisal of the actual differences between groups that doesn't contain the fuzziness of sampling variation, etc.

Hopefully its clear from the other useful answers here and mine that it really depends on whether or not you seek to extrapolate to the rest of the world or if you are solely centered on making determinations of the groups directly in front of you.

Answer (score 8):

In the first place it is important to realise that nobody else than you yourself can decide what you are interested in! It is a bit strange to ask us what you should be interested in. This is connected with my observation that very often people are not aware of how the choice of appropriate analysis depends on their own decisions and interest, and they have to take responsibility for this. Rather there seems to be an idea that there is some "objectively correct" method for analysing any given set of data.

But then we also need to understand that our own interest may be more nuanced than it seems at first sight.

Are the males or females in your class doing better with the course material? Computing descriptive statistics and making visualisations (you may want to do that as computing means reduces information about the full distribution that may be relevant) will allow you to compare how these particular people did in a specific exam (I don't call this "test" and keep that term for statistical tests). If this is what you want to know that's fine, and no statistical test contributes to answering that question. But you may be interested in more - (a) is there evidence that males or females do *generally* better in that exam, and (b) thinking that there may be a random element in the performance of every student ("good or bad day"), is there evidence anyway that the males or females *in your class* do better than the other "party"?

These questions are clearly not addressed by descriptive statistics and visualisation, and the idea may be tempting that a statistical tests addresses these.

Some other people have written about hypothetical or "superpopulations". Let's say you compare results using a t-test. This in fact compares the real exam results to a distribution that you would expect in a hypothetical superpopulation that is i.i.d. normally distributed with same mean in the two groups. Does in make sense to think about your situation in such terms (and which sense does it exactly make)? This is not such an easy question.

The first thing is to realise that any real group or situation you may want to generalise to will be quite different. A major issue here is dependence. Some of your students will have learnt together, and there is interaction between them (and between them and you) in the classroom. For this reason, any outcome of your specific class may not generalise well to an assumed i.i.d. population, and your observations should be expected to behave differently from what is specified in the model underlying the test. Also thinking about random outcomes for the *same* students isn't really in line with an i.i.d. model because in that case you want to generalise outcomes to other hypothetical results (the same students on a different day, say) that are clearly not independent.

Now "all models are wrong but some are useful", so in general you will always find issues with any model if you look for them enough. It will pay off to think thoroughly about whether possible issues with the model will have the potential to give you misleading conclusions. For example normality is obviously violated because (a) the value range is limited and (b) results are not continuous, but in many cases it can be shown by running a t-test on corresponding simulated i.i.d. (!) data that these model violations are actually harmless.

With dependence though things are worse. For example, if there is positive correlation between any two observations in your data, the i.i.d.-based variance will be underestimated and precision of your results will be overestimated, so you will reject your null hypothesis of equality easier than it should be the case - it depends on the strength of dependence *how much* easier. And note that such correlation *cannot be diagnosed from the data*, see [Hennig, C. Parameters not empirically identifiable or distinguishable, including correlation between Gaussian observations. Stat Papers (2023).](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00362-023-01414-3)

That said, I could in such a situation still be interested in running the test, just in order to have an indication of how random variability could play out in this situation assuming an artificial model for "both groups equal", even if this doesn't correspond to any meaningful superpopulation. In case of non-significance it would still show that the data do not give any convincing indication for a systematic difference in means, as data are compatible with a simplified random model in which all differences between males and females are just random variation. However I'd do that having in mind that a significant result doesn't necessarily say anything meaningful of interest. Sure, it will reject a model for "equal means", but this model here is not realistic in the first place, and not only that, it is *unrealistic in ways that may cause significance even if the null hypothesis your are really interested in were true*, which is that males and females are not systematically different regarding your exam, and significance could just have been caused by dependence.

I'd say that this would be a rather "exploratory" use of the test, which I'm confident about because I know what I'm doing. It may be problematic to recommend this to other people because they may just read too much into a rejection. Which will hopefully not apply to you, at least not after reading this. :-)

On the other hand, given the issue with the hypothetical superpopulation that may either not exist or if it exists not be in line with the model underlying the standard test, it is absolutely legitimate to do descriptive and exporatory statistics only without making reference to probability models, "significance" and the like. Only make sure that you do not generalise when interpreting results, as there is nothing in these procedures that allows for generalisation. Things are as they are and that's it (but understanding more precisely how they are can be worthwhile enough).

Answer (score 7):

> I am not interested in making claims about a larger population of
> students, am I?

It would be incorrect to make claims relative to a larger population, like students from other classes in the same school, students at the national or international level, or even other students who attended the same class but in different years.

For instance, changes in education policies, as well as economic crises, wars, [epidemics](https://unesdoc.unesco.org/ark:/48223/pf0000380398), and other factors external to the potential of individual students, may have an impact on how cohorts of students from different years are able to answer a test successfully - so you shouldn't consider students from a given year as a random sample of all past and future students who take the same test over the years.

Peter Flom mentions the super population argument in his answer. Like him, I'm not very convinced by this point of view, at least in the context of your question. My guess is that you're problably interested in saying something about the students you have in your class, not about hypothetical students who do not exist. But it's up to you to decide what you're interested in.

A risk here, in particular when you say that you tend to dismiss descriptive statistics, is to think that because inferential statistics do not hint to a difference between two (or more) groups, there isn't one. If you incorrectly think that, you could dismiss an actual problem in your class because your sample is not informative enough (e.g. women being at a structural disadvantage for some reason, reflected in smaller grades, but with a too small sample size to allow you to identify the problem through hypothesis testing or confidence intervals). So you shouldn't dismiss information that descriptive statistics can give you. As an aside, this is also true about information you could get from more qualitative observations, e.g. interviews with students, other teachers, social workers, etc.

Comment: I see your point now, you're totally right!

Comment: I don't agree with the final paragraph that inferential statistics risks dismissing a true problem due to small sample size. A lack of a significant difference should not in general be interpreted as indicating a lack of a difference - it just indicates you don't have sufficient evidence to conclude a difference. Seeing no significant difference and concluding there is no difference is simply misapplying inferential statistics. Also, that fact that we're trying to determine if there is a problem suggests to me that we do want to address it in a future population with similar characteristics.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie You're absolutely right, this paragraph was bad or clumsy at best. Thanks for pointing the issue. I tried to rewrite it in light of your comment. I think that what pushed me to write it in the first place was to read "*I tend to discard simple descriptive statistic because they do not account in any way for randomness*" in the original question, which is a type of statement I encounter from time to time and that I find often related to the kind of fallacy you mention.

Answer (score 5):

"I want to see whether females **are doing** better than males."

This line says to me that this is not a one-off observation to determine who did do better on this one particular test. Rather, the use of "are doing" (instead of "did") suggests an ongoing evaluation period with tests that haven't even been taken yet. You are probably going to use the results of this test to reason about the broader population of tests over the entire semester. You don't need much in the way of inferential statistics to determine who did better on this single test, but by asking the question in this setting, you're probably interested in the broader question of if this is a trend you're likely to see in the future as well. Of course, you should consider what general population you might be justified in reasoning about (the same class later in the semester is probably OK, but reasoning about another class at another university 10 years from now probably is not).

Suppose you tabulate the results of the test and find that one gender did 50 points worse than the other. It would be quite reasonable to try to use that information to adjust your teaching style, which implicitly is using the test scores to reason about future, unseen populations. You'll treat the result differently if it is a "real" result, compared to a statistical fluke. On the other hand, if all you need to know is who scored higher on this single test to win the end-of-semester pizza party, there is no need to infer anything else about other populations. In this latter case, it doesn't really matter at all if the winning side won because they're truly better or because they got lucky.

Comment: "if this is a trend you're likely to see in the future as well". Changes in education policies can make this kind of inference very incorrect (e.g. in another comment, I mention the example of some generations of high school students who did not have mandatory teaching in maths, and this had a very strong negative effect on women), so you can't draw conclusions only from the sample without considering external phenomenons. (It doesn't mean the sample can't be informative, but it isn't enough, and may even be misleading).

Comment: @J-J-J Of course, using inferential statistics to make inferences about unseen population requires assuming that the observed and unobserved populations are, in fact, the same. It's probably reasonable to use the performance on one test to reason about performance in the same class later in the semester, but perhaps not to reason about performance in another class in another university years later.

Comment: True (+1), so I think we don't disagree on principle. In short, the thing is to be extra careful, and knowing the social and institutional environment very well before drawing conclusions, e.g. maybe taking additional advice from social workers in the community if we suspect that something might be going on.

Answer (score 3):

I think the previous comments do an excellent job of explaining the intricacies of samples and populations and how that relates to what YOU want to know - this is really the important bit that decides whether you "get away" with descriptive statistics. As you saw (based on the different answers you got) it is not easy to phrase such a question unambiguously, i.e. in a way that everyone will map your question to the same kind of statistical analysis.
Whether or not you can actually answer the question you decided to pose in a satisfying manner, however, depends crucially on the data you have and the assumptions you are willing to make.

Assuming your only data so far are individual scores on the intermediate test, so no other tests, no other assignments etc., and it is the first time you are doing this class, so you do not have information about previous cohorts:

- Descriptive statistics will tell you whether your current females got better results than your current males on this test. Some people might find this boring but maybe that is something you want to know - who are we to judge, right? There is not much involved beyond that, except maybe that calculating means requires an interval scale.
- However, you seem to feel uncomfortable with this and be more interested in rather general statements about gender effects in your intermediate test. This is where the fun starts: A t-test takes randomness by gender into account, so with the p-value you are getting the probability for the difference you observed (or more extreme ones) under the assumption that there is no population difference in mean test scores on this intermediate test by gender. Here you have to think hard about which level of significance you would actually require to take action (if at all), and concepts like false negatives/positives, power etc., should come into consideration.

-> Note that I wrote "test score on this intermediate test" and this is important. The intermediate itself is regarded as fixed. This means the result of the t-test does not provide information by itself about future intermediate tests (or any other test, for that matter), as long as you do not use the same one again (in which case you might run into other issues because students are connected, and males maybe differently than females, leading to different result-differences in the future). When you want to consider the randomness of "intermediate test", you are basically at a loss here, because that is an n = 1 study at this point. So any statement along the lines of "females are doing better than males on intermediate tests" is you buying into the assumption that the administration of different intermediate tests would have yielded the same results (or very similar ones, because the relative statement "better" grants some leeway here). This is true for other supposedly varying factors involving student performance, e.g., how you taught the class, the examples you gave, etc. - all fixed.

-> the next big point is that results in a test are not necessarily equal to skill. You write you want to know whether females are "doing better". In the broader sense and from a teacher's perspective, you might want to know whether students actually learn anything and what their abilities are instead of how many answers they get right - the latter is just your measurement instrument for the former. However, when you directly compare the raw scores as a skill estimate, you are buying into the assumption that this instrument actually works the same in both genders, and this is not necessarily true. The concept behind this assumption is called measurement (non-)invariance, and it asks whether measurement processes work the same in the groups you are interested in. If that is not the case, mean differences might be due to the measurement instrument (the intermediate test, e.g. due to how the questions are phrased), but not due to the concept you wanted to measure (skill). This can be hugely problematic because you might conclude that one gender does not learn well in your class when it is actually your abilities in phrasing test questions that is driving this difference.

-> Additionally, information outside the classroom are also beyond the t-test, such as events affecting people from different gender differently, and have also an effect on test scores (i.e., unobserved confounders). So an event which upsets the boys in your class in a way that reduces their focus will influence your results in a way that erroneously lets you jump into some kind of action.

So a very precise question is really the most important aspect - going from there you can think about the data you need and the assumptions you would be willing to buy into. And of course, there are other questions possible, such as predicting the overall course grade (individuals or groups) or comparing results across cohorts, which come with their own assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

Statistics is more than about sampling.  Statistics is about making a conclusion - extracting meaning - from incomplete information.

If you simply repeat the information you are provided, then statistics isn't being used.  If you summarize, interpret, or express it differently, then you are using Statistics.

When you take the average of a set of test scores by a student, what is it you are doing?  Is it merely the mechanical sum of test scores divided by the count?  No, not really: nobody would care about the average of a set of test scores if it was an arbitrary mechanical operation.

If it was an arbitrary mechanical operation, why not divide it by 3.14?  Or multiply each test score by its test score number, add that up, then divide by the number of test scores squared?  Both of these contain about the same amount of information about the original test scores, but aren't something you are doing.

It is the properties of the average that you care about.  Often you'll implicitly use the linear average to try to describe what score the student would do get given more testing on the same subject, usually with some validity.

And many people don't even consider the spectrum of averages - geometric, logarithmic, the p-family, etc - that often have the very same properties that the linear average has.  They just use the linear average out of habit.

Even a test score - 70/100 say - is a fraction of the tested material the student understood.  A student with a consistently high test score you presume has a grasp of the material, while one with a consistently low test score you presume does not.

You could imaging a better mechanism for evaluating understanding of material; factor analysis, for example, could be used on a set of tests to determine which students lack understanding of which topics, and even to get a measure of how well the course teaches a given topic by correlating the score in a topic with other scores.  As a concrete example of this, a psychology professor once used this to figure out which questions they had failed to teach the class (questions whose answer was highly uncorrelated with higher marks), based off of the idea if the answer wasn't correlated with studying the material it was a teaching failure.  They had a cut off, and reduced the denominator of their exams by their failed questions (they became "bonus questions" implicitly), then sought to improve the next iteration of instruction and examination.

All of these tools produce a signal, and part of Statistics is understanding if that signal is spurious.  Like, if you want to know if blue jelly beans are tastier to your class.  You blind taste test, and ask your subjects to rate how tasty each of a bunch of jelly beans are.  The thing is, the rating someone gives a jelly bean will contain "how tasty" information plus other information you don't care about, like the mood of the student, if the student's clothing itches, the order they tasted the jelly bean, etc.

You can attempt to measure the magnitude of this "random factor" by looking at the distribution of ratings.  If there is a large random factor, you'd usually get more variation in sample values.

So the degree to which the blue jelly beans got a higher taste score needs to be compared to the amount of variance in the signal in an attempt to determine if the higher (or lower) taste score of the jelly bean is from the jelly bean itself, or uncontrolled external random factors.

All of this applies to how you use information about your students test scores.  If you want to simply state what they are and don't interpret them, you are fine.

But if you even take an average, or compare two subpopulation averages against each other, and don't want to be deceptive, you should use Statistical tools to determine if what you are highlighting is just noise or it is a meaningful signal.  You are doing this manipulation to produce a story (even if an implicit one), and without statistical tools that story will quite likely be untrue.

It is really easy to lie with numbers by accident.